# alternative of pdfinfo to display author and title

Tags: pdf

I am using pdfinfo to display the title name and author of pdf files. But for some pdf files, it's not working. It's showing all other info like creation date,modification date,pagesize etc  except title of the paper and authors name. Is there any alternative way to retrieve these info? I have used:

```
pdfinfo filename
```

Comment: Are you sure the other PDFs do have a tilte/author at all?

Comment: when i read them, the  title is at the top, and below it, the author names are written @Thomas Erker

Comment: @Black That doesn't mean that the title and author are indicated as title and author in the PDF metadata. If they aren't, then that's just line 1 and line 2 as far as `pdfinfo` is concerned.

Answer (score 6):

For pdfinfo to display the title, it must be specified in the metadata field title. The title that it displays it's not the pdf "physical" filename if that is what you're trying to get.

Use a graphic explorer to view the file properties and in the metadata tab make sure you have a title. In the image bellow you can see that they can have different values

[image]

---

Edit: For an alternative to pdfinfo you can use [exiftool](http://xmodulo.com/view-or-edit-pdf-and-image-metadata-from-command-line-on-linux.html) to read/write files metadata. For example to get title and author you could do this:

```
exiftool -Title -Author input.pdf
```

Comment: Suppose, I have a research paper which is in pdf format named paper.pdf but the actual title of the paper is  " Future aspects of Science" which is written on the top of the paper when I open it and the writer's name is/are also written below the title (say: Mr. A and Mr. B).So, I want to retrieve these info:
Title: Future aspects of Science
Author: Mr. A and Mr. B
Is there any way of doing this? @Pedro Mendes

Comment: @Black Use `pdftotext` or some such and extract the first and second line (perhaps after skipping headers, and perhaps coping with multi-line titles and authors, etc).